# Translating source-code into Java

Tags: programming, source-code, translation

## Source-to-Source Conversion

I need to translate much [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) from an obscure programming language into Java.

The other language is relatively simple, [Pascal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language))-like. No [structs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)), no [objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Has `if` tests and `for`/`while` loops similar to Java. No [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) in the C-sense, but has references that I think I can map to Java references. The obscure language has a thousand specialized commands that I am re-implementing in Java as static class method calls.

I am only talking about source-code, *not* compiling or [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) generation/manipulation. After my translation tool generates Java source-code, that Java code will become a normal Java project in a regular Java IDE for the usual Java compiler and JVM.

I suspect that a search-and-replace approach will not work well for this source-to-source conversion. At the very least of many possible problems, I need to skip over quoted string literal statements.

I have only recently learned that there may be tools that are aware of programming languages as such, and capable of manipulating source code in a fashion more intelligent than mere search-and-replace.

### Antlr

I have heard of the [*Antlr*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) project for generating lexers/parsers.

In this tool, I first define a formal [BNF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)-like [grammar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) to describe this obscure programming language. Then Antlr uses that grammar to generate a lexer/parser built in Java source code. I give that lexer/parser a chunk of my obscure language source code to generate an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)  representing the identifiers, keywords, operators, and values in that source code. I can then use the tree-parser feature of Antlr 4 to visit the nodes of that AST. As I visit each node, my code uses [*StringTemplate*](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) project to generate Java source code as the translation from obscure language to Java language.

- Am I correct in my understanding of Antlr? (I am new to this idea of tools that understand and manipulate a programming language.)
- Is Antlr the best tool for this job?
- How onerous and enormous a task is defining a grammar?

  - Is my time better spent learning search-and-replace tools such as [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)/[AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)/[sed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)/[Perl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) given how close my obscure language may be to Java?
  - Should I look for an existing grammar definition for some Pascal-like language that I could then edit to fit my obscure programming language rather than start a grammar from scratch?

### Yacc

I have also heard of the older [*Yacc*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) tool. From what little I know, Antlr is basically Yacc on steroids.

- Is there any advantage to Yacc over Antlr or other tools for my purpose of source-to-source conversion?

Comment: There is also JavaCC, which is pretty flexible. But note that "all" what these tools do is to generate Java code to parse your particular language. Basically it translates a description of your *language* into Java. It doesn't translate any code *written in such a language to Java*.  Being able to parse your language is only the first part of the solution.